# Хранение файлов на сервере.

Tags: fileupload, сервер

Всем привет. Создавая сайт, задался вопросом - как лучше изначально хранить файлы, а точнее изображения пользователей.
Хотелось бы разработать сайт сразу, для того, чтобы при росте пользователей можно было легко усилить место для хранения файлов.
Изначально, при старте, будет взят VPS.

Есть варианты хранения:
 1. На том же сервере, в подпапке.
 2. На поддомене. ([img.site.com](http://img.site.com))
 3. На отдельном сервере. (Крайне не желательно).

Статьи в интернете не смог найти по этому поводу. Нашел, что якобы на поддомене лучше всего хранить, так как уменьшается нагрузка, некоторые говорят, что разницы нет. Но, меня и волнует такой вопрос - чтобы в дальнейшем было легко перенести на отдельный сервер. В базе данных собираюсь хранить полную ссылку до файла изображения (будет ли так лучше всего?) Например в базе сохраняем:(http://img.site.com/p/user/tW84Ghw87GhPi.png).

В чем собственно проблема заключается: Нужно разработать сайт уже готовый, для более легкого переноса новых фотографий на новый сервер и так же волнует оптимизация и нагрузка на сервер.
Хотелось бы узнать так же о методах загрузка на разные способы. Первый, я знаю, загружается обычным способом. На счет второго затруднения, обычный способ не поддерживает загрузку по юрл, по-моему. А третий способ работает через ФТП?

За ранее спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Исходя из вашей поставленной задачи и того, что вы собираетесь брать VPS, я не вижу особого смысла переживать о нагрузке на сервер. VPS обычно берут для гораздо более сложных задач, например, для работы php-демона.

Во-вторых, если вы собираетесь мигрировать, то не надо хранить пути к изображениям в таком виде, как вы показали. Для первого варианта (хранить в подпапке), достаточно делать путь от корня "/p/user/tW84Ghw87GhPi.png". Тогда, при смене сервера или доменого имени, вам не нужно будет боротся с головной болью, связанной с новыми путями.

Хранить же изображения на отдельном хосте, имеет смысл, если вы планируете часто переезжать основным сайтом на "новое место", но это как-то лишено логики, или для страховки от "несчастных случаев". По поводу хранения на поддомене - опять же, при переезде, вы столкнетесь с определенными трудностями в отношении путей.

В общем, на мой взгляд, надо четко определиться с возможными путями вашего развития и только тогда выбирать какой-то из вариантов. При определенных условиях, все они могут иметь смысл. Для справки - "одноклассники" хранять изображения на поддомене, а "вконтакте" - на отдельном сервере.

Comment: Спасибо, за информацию. Для начала буду хранить все в подпапках, после можно хранить информацию на других серверах.

Comment: Ммм... спасибо конечно, за "верный ответ", но спешить не надо )) Думаю, что кроме моего, будут еще ответы, которые могут дать более исчерпывающую информацию. Просто воскресенье и многие не успели добраться до вашего вопроса  ;)

Comment: Думаю, вы правы, может кто-нибудь еще подкинет умных вещей. =)